# Unable to get /refresh to work with spring-cloud-client when server.port and management.port are different

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config

Below is the application.properties for a spring-boot application

```
spring.application.name=test-service
server.port=8080

management.port=8081
management.context-path=/admin

spring.cloud.config.uri=http://localhost:8888
endpoints.refresh.enabled=true
endpoints.restart.enabled=true
```

When I start the application, it contacts the config-server and loads the properties as expected.

I modify the properties on the config server and trigger a refresh on the application using

```
curl -X POST http://localhost:8081/admin/refresh
```

the API prints the name of the property that was changed.

When I do a get on the property, I still see the old value

```
curl -X GET http://localhost:8081/admin/env/{property_name}
```

I trigger a restart and it picks up the the new property value

```
curl -X POST http://localhost:8081/admin/restart
```

See the same behavior when I try to change the property value using

```
curl -X POST  http://localhost:8081/admin/env -d property1=123
```

When I try to get the property value I still see the old value

```
curl -X GET http://localhost:8081/admin/env/property1
```

When I change the management.port to 8080 (the same as the server.port) everything works as expected.

Is this behavior expected? Looks to me that it is modifying 2 different environments one for the server running on 8080 and the other running on 8081.

Answer (score 1):

Could you please share your pom.xml and application main(Entry) file.No matter we can use different port. If you are able to get the changed properties in "/refresh" call then it should work in your application also. Are you sure you are using @RefreshScope in your bean?

Note : @RefreshScope will not work on @Configuration annotation.for further details please follow the documentation https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/spring-cloud-config.html.

Answer (score 0):

Looks to be an issue with spring-boot.

EnvironmentEndpoint and EnvironmentMVCEndpoint are injected with 2 different Environments when the server.port and management.port are different.

The application environment has the updated value but when I get the value of a specific property EnviromentMVCEndpoint it does not reflect the right value in its Environment

```
@GetMapping(value = "/{name:.*}", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@ResponseBody
@HypermediaDisabled
public Object value(@PathVariable String name) {
    if (!getDelegate().isEnabled()) {
        // Shouldn't happen - MVC endpoint shouldn't be registered when delegate's
        // disabled
        return getDisabledResponse();
    }
    return new NamePatternEnvironmentFilter(this.environment).getResults(name);
}

@Override
public void setEnvironment(Environment environment) {
    this.environment = environment;
}
```